# Why can't Math.Net Numerics resolve creator?

Tags: c#, openblas, mathnet-numerics

Math.Net Numerics returning

> "Native Provider Probing failed to resolve creator" when trying to use MKL or OpenBLAS

I'm trying to enable acceleration using either MKL or OpenBLAS on a Windows machine.

I've added both Nuget packages, and it now seems to be finding the dlls.

However I get an error saying:

> NotSupportedException: Native Provider Probing failed to resolve
> creator at `MathNet.Numerics.Providers.ProviderProbe'1.Create()` at
> `MathNet.Numerics.Control.UseNativeOpenBLAS()`

when calling:

```
MathNet.Numerics.Control.UseNativeOpenBLAS();
```

What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT 1]

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double; 
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearRegression; 
using MathNet.Numerics.Providers.OpenBLAS; 
using MathNet.Numerics.Providers.MKL;
```

Nuget packages:

```
MathNet.Numerics
MathNet.Numerics.MKL.Win-x64
MathNet.Numerics.Providers.OpenBLAS
```

[EDIT 2]
If I change my code to this:

```
    const string OpenBlasTypeName = "MathNet.Numerics.Providers.OpenBLAS.LinearAlgebra.OpenBlasLinearAlgebraControl, MathNet.Numerics.Providers.OpenBLAS";
    var OpenBlasProbe = new ProviderProbe<ILinearAlgebraProvider>(OpenBlasTypeName, AppSwitches.DisableOpenBlasNativeProvider);
    var x1 = OpenBlasProbe.Create();

    MathNet.Numerics.Control.UseNativeOpenBLAS();
```

then it seems to get further, I don't know why. Now the error I get is:

> `NotSupportedException: OpenBLAS Native Provider not found. ---> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libMathNetNumericsOpenBLAS': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) at query_capability in at MathNet.Numerics.Providers.OpenBLAS.SafeNativeMethods.query_capability(Int32 capability) at MathNet.Numerics.Providers.OpenBLAS.OpenBlasProvider.Load(String hintPath)`

I can't find libMathNetNumericsOpenBLAS.dll anywhere - what do I do?

Comment: Please share the code, packages, and references (using XX)